# Select multiple ManytoMany en Django

Tags: python, django

Necesito crear un multiselect con los valores de un campo ManyToManyField, en un template de html en Django.

Mi archivo model.py

```
from othermodel.models import Othermodel

class whatever(models.Model):
    whateverfield = models.ManyToManyField(Othermodel,related_name="whateverfield")
```

Mi archivo form.py

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = whatever
    fields = (
        'whateverfield'
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['whateverfield'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Othermodel.objects.all(), 
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple,)
```

Mi archivo views.html

```
   @login_required
  def whatever_edit(request,pk):

    if request.method == 'POST':
       #guarda el formulario de edit.html sin problema
    else:
       form = PostForm()

    whatever = Whatever.objects.filter(pk=pk).prefetch_related('othermodel')
    Othermodel = Othermodel.objects.all()

   return render(request, 'casinos/edit.html', {
     'whatever': whatever,
     'Othermodel': Othermodel,
   })
```

Y el select en mi archivo edit.html, el cual obviamente está erroneo:

```
        <select name="whatever" class="form-control" multiple>
         {% for w in Othermodel %}
         {% for c in whatever.Othermodel.all %}
         {% if c.id == w.id %}
         <option value="{{w.id}}" selected="selected">{{w.name}}</option>
         {% else %}
          <option value="{{w.id}}">{{w.name}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
         {% endif %}
         {% endfor %}
         </select>
```

He intentado con comprehensions, pero no he dado con la tecla ya que son bastantes complejos en los templates de Django. También he intentado reproducirlo mediante {{form.whateverfield}} pero no me salen seleccionados los valores.

Edito:
He intentado utilizar UpdateView, pero no se como mostrar un multiselect

```
    <select class="form-control {% if form.game_provider.errors %}is-invalid{% endif %}" name="game_provider" multiple="multiple"/>
    <option value="{% if form.errors %}{{ form.game_provider.value }}{% else %}{{ casinos.game_provider.all }}{% endif %}"></option> 
   </select>
```

Porque {{form.as_table}} y {{form.as_p}}, además de devolverme el formulario sin estilos, me devuelve los options del multiselect con:

whatever.object(1)
whatever.object(2)

Comment: Lo q deseas es q al cargarse el select tenga seleccionado por defecto un option???

Comment: Si, se trata del form de editar, me gustaría que ya estuvieran seleccionados por defecto los datos que ya están en la bd.

Comment: Ok entonces usa una vista generica, UpdateView, le pasas el modelo y automáticamente se cargarán todos los datos, de otro modo,si sólo deseas cargar campos específicos te envío el código dentro de un rato.

Comment: Pues sería muy amable por tu parte, si sabes como mostrar ese Select Multiple porque lo he intentado de muchas formas. No me suele gustar mucho utilizar Generic Views, aunque lo he intentado también y tampoco consigo cargar los valores.

Comment: He utilizado UpdateView y he editado la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

Mi archivo views.py

```
   class UpdateCasinos(UpdateView):
       form_class = PostForm
       model = Whatever
       template_name = 'Whatever/edit.html'
       success_url = '/Whatever/'

      def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

         pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)

         whatever = Whatever.objects.get(pk=pk)
         form = PostForm(request.POST or None, instance=whatever)

         if request.POST and form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
         else:
             errors = form.errors
             return render(request, self.template_name, {
                'form':form,
                'errors':errors
             })
```

Y mi archivo form.py

```
from django.forms.models import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class MyMultipleModelChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "%s" % (obj.name)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Whatever
        fields = (
            'whateverfield',
            )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # call the parent init
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['whateverfield'] = MyMultipleModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Whatever.objects.all(), 
            required=True, 
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos podrias intentar usando el widget:

Tengo los siguientes **models**:

```
class Tema(models.Model):
    TEMA_CHOICES = (
        ('tecnologia', 'Tecnologia'),
        ('novela', 'Novela'),
        ('psicologia', 'Psicologia'),
    )
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=TEMA_CHOICES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

class Libro(models.Model):
  ...
  ..
   temas = models.ManyToManyField(Tema)
```

en mi **form** seria algo así:

```
from django import forms
from miApp.models import Tema, Libro

class LibroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ....
    ....
    temas = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Tema.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

en mi template:

```
{{ form.temas }}
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Si te das cuenta en mi archivo form.py ya tengo un widget. El problema es cuando pongo {{form.wathever}} no se selecciona ningún option.

Answer (score 1):

Mira en este proyecto esto fue lo q hice

```
class AddPub(CreateView):
      model=Pub
      form_class=PubForm
      template_name='plantilla.html'
     success_url='/url'

     def get(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
             form = self.form_class(initial={'nombre campo 
             select':'valores a marcar'})
              return render(request, self.template_name, context={'form':form})
```

Espero te sirva